# pyinstaller not finding pyobjc library (MacOS; python)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pyinstaller, pyobjc, nsautoreleasepool

I'm trying to package a python (2.7) application on Mac, using pyinstaller.
My code uses NSAutoreleasePool from PyObjC, but for some reason pyinstaller can't find this library, even though python can see it just fine. 
For example, if I have test.py with a single line:

```
from Foundation import NSAutoreleasePool
```

then running

```
python test.py
```

works just fine, but if I try to package this using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

then in warntest.txt I get the following warning:

```
"W: no module named Foundation.NSAutoreleasePool (top-level import by __main__)"
```

And if I try running the packaged application, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name NSAutoreleasePool
```

I tried adding '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC' to pathex in the spec file, but that wasn't the right thing to do, now the application crashes with the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/lenka/Desktop/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/Foundation", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/lenka/Desktop/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/CoreFoundation", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Users/lenka/Desktop/test/build/test/out00-PYZ.pyz/objc._bridgesupport", line 121, in initFrameworkWrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 873, in resource_exists
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1308, in has_resource
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1361, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
logout
```

I can't figure out what else to try. I will very much appreciate any advice, thank you in advance!

Comment: Okay, so this worked:

`import Foundation`
`from Foundation import NSAutoreleasePool`
I don't quite understand why this made a difference for Pyinstaller, but somehow it did. If someone knows why this worked, I would appreciate an explanation -- but I'm happy something worked!

Comment: I have similar issue with from PyObjCTools import AppHelper. I tried importing PyObjCTools first. Not working.